# Generating HSQLDB tables in memory from JPA/EclipseLink (no files)

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink, hsqldb, in-memory-database

I have JPA2 with EclipseLink 2.4, and I'm trying to implement an in-memory database using HSQLDB. I have been able to create a file implementation of the hsqldb using

```
jdbc:hsqldb:file:./databases/test;shutdown=true;files_readonly=true
```

But when I try to use `jdbc:hsqldb:mem:tableName`, I get the following message:

---

Stacktrace:

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse   
Persistence Services - 2.4.0.v20120608-r11652):  
  org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: user lacks privilege or object
  not found: EFFECTIVITY

Error Code: -5501
Call: INSERT INTO EFFECTIVITY (HULL) VALUES (?)
bind => [1 parameter bound]
Query: InsertObjectQuery(101)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.flush
       (EntityManagerImpl.java:804)
at com.gdeb.touchtable.db.TestJPAEntities.testTTTouch(TestJPAEntities.java:93)
..............
Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: user lacks privilege or object not found:
 EFFECTIVITY
at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.SchemaManager.getTable(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.readTableName(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.readRangeVariableForDataChange(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.ParserDML.compileInsertStatement(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.ParserCommand.compilePart(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.ParserCommand.compileStatement(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.Session.compileStatement(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.StatementManager.compile(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.Session.execute(Unknown Source)
... 63 more
```

---

From what I read, the data model should be generated automagically, but I have only seen examples with Hibernate. Is there a way to link the JPA data-model and create it using the memory mode of HSQLDB?

Comment: I'm doing testing in several different environments, and I don't need to retain the data afterwards, nor do I need files clogging up the repository, so HSQLDB seems like a good way to do it.

Comment: I have no experiences with an in-memory HSQLDB and JPA.  But I have had success using the H2 database.

Comment: @WernerVesterås H2 also looks promising :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If what is missing are the tables, you need to set the eclipselink.ddl-generation property with a value of "create-tables" to have Eclipselink create them for you.  An example is posted here: http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/DDL

Comment: For others having the same problem, you might have to specify the 'target-database' property: `eclipselink.target-database` which is `org.eclipse.persistence.platform.database.HSQLPlatform` for HSQLDB.

Comment: where we should use this link property.please help me.